# Listen to Realm insert/update/delete and see the old value and new value when changed

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to build an audit trail into my application.

Is it possible on Android to listen to a Realm change, then when an object is updated see it's old value AND the new value?

I believe this is the current functionality on iOS (returning an old/new pair on change), but I cannot seem to find anything referencing this functionality for Android.

Comment: Nope, in Android you always see only the latest value. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EpicPandaForce was correct, in Android you always see only the latest value.